# Dividing a text into multiple pages

Tags: pdf, ckeditor

Currently, I'm creating an application where my client creates invoices and offers. To let him create an offer, I'm using CkEditor. This all works fine but he's also able to export this offer to a PDF-document. Sometimes he sees that some text divides into multiple pages. Because of the fact this sometimes happens at places he don't want this, he asked me to create a function that shows him a page divider while editing.

What I've done now is showing an image (position absolute, behind the text) on a calculated position, 1700px from top or from the last divide-image. For some reason I think this could be better, what do you think is the best way to do this?

Example: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2a7w.jpg

Comment: You could use a `page-break-before` CSS attribute for a certain element in your HTML: http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

Comment: That's true, I could add that attribute but then I have to know if the element will break so I can dynamically add the attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Try if your pdf generator respects `page-break-before`, `page-break-after` and `page-break-inside`.

```
@media print {
    /* Always start a chapter on new page. */
    h1 { page-break-before: always; } 

    /* Keeps lines together */
    p { page-break-inside: avoid; }

    /* A custom page break element. */ 
    /* Add styling for editing but hide visibility in the rendered document. */
    hr { page-break-after: always; visibility: hidden; }
}
```

Comment: Well, this works, but before generating a PDF, I don't know if a certain image is placed on the current page or the next one (because it didnt fit the previous page..)

Comment: Custom breakpoints give the user some control over where breaks occur. It doesn't mean that unwanted breaks can never occur. Only that the user has the tools to fix breaks as needed. Most publishing software have paragraph rules. They can keep n lines of the same paragraph together. CSS doesn't have this feature. The page break estimator is hard because you only can make a very rough estimate about the size of complex content (and never get it exactly right). Give the user the tools to correct bad breaks and be done with it. It's better for the  end result, user and developer.

Comment: I added a pagebreak-button to my ckeditor-toolbar so users can fix these breaks if needed. What could help is to give the user a little hint, what I've done now is:

`var pageheight = 1430;

var height=$('.page').height()+173;
amount=Math.ceil(height/pageheight);
for(i=1;i<=amount;i++){
   $('.page').append('<div style="position:absolute;top:'+(pageheight*i)+'px"><input type="hidden" name="blocks[]" value="block_idhr" /><img style="margin-left:-52px;" src="/crm/resources/images/pageline.png" /></div>');
}` But if there's a pagebreak inside the editor, i want to count from the pagebreak.